# Ubuntu 20.04 Restarted itself

Tags: gnome

While I was working on my project Ubuntu 20.04 suddenly restarted itself

What should i do?

Linux Kernel 5.4

Comment: The most logical thing to do would be to check the system log. This would be `/var/log/syslog`, and look for any messages that were written around the time of the system restart. If the system had to restart itself without warning, then there should be *something* written to explain why. Then you can update your question (or make a new one) with that information to try and find a solution.

Comment: What kind of a project were you working on? Please be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fast fluctuation in the incoming current that lasts less than one second can cause a forced restart on some hardware, for example if your computer is connected to the source of electricity through a surge protector.